# How to use dynamically allocated memory in C

Tags: c, memory-management, scilab, xcos

I have been developing a block in Scilab/Xcos (open source variant of Matlab/Simulink) with C language usage. For that purpose the Scilab/Xcos offers a special block called CBLOCK4. As soon as I place this block into the simulation a C language stub is automatically generated. Part of that stub is a template for a function which implements the behavior of the block. This function accepts among its parameters pointer to a `scicos_block` structure:

```
typedef struct {
  int nevprt;
  voidg funpt ;
  int type;
  int scsptr;
  int nz;
  double *z;
  int noz;
  int *ozsz;
  int *oztyp;
  void **ozptr;
  int nx;
  double *x;
  double *xd;
  double *res;
  int nin;
  int *insz;
  void **inptr;
  int nout;
  int *outsz;
  void **outptr;
  int nevout;
  double *evout;
  int nrpar;
  double *rpar;
  int nipar;
  int *ipar;
  int nopar;
  int *oparsz;
  int *opartyp;
  void **oparptr;
  int ng;
  double *g;
  int ztyp;
  int *jroot;
  char *label;
  void **work;
  int nmode;
  int *mode;
} scicos_block;
```

The item `work` is probably intended to be used for storage of the address at which another address is stored at which the internal state variables of the block are stored. I have attempted to implement the Scilab/Xcos block with the `work` item usage:

```
#include "scicos_block4.h"

#define U  ((double *)GetRealInPortPtrs(block, 1))
#define Y  ((double *)GetRealOutPortPtrs(block, 1))

// parameters
#define Tu (GetRparPtrs(block)[0])
#define Td (GetRparPtrs(block)[1])
#define T  (GetRparPtrs(block)[2])


void Ramp(scicos_block *block, int flag)
{
 
  double *target;
  double *inputDelta;
  double *out;

  if(flag == 4) 
  {
    /* init */
    if((*(block->work) = (double *)scicos_malloc(sizeof(double)*3)) == NULL)
    {
        set_block_error(-16);
        return;
    }
        
    target      = (double*)(*(block->work));
    inputDelta  = (double*)(*(block->work + 1));
    out         = (double*)(*(block->work + 2));

    *target     = 0;
    *inputDelta = 0;
    *out        = 0; 

  }
  else if(flag == 1) 
  {
    /* output computation */ 
    if(U[0] != *target)
    {
        *target = U[0];
        
        if(*target - Y[0] < 0)
        {
            *inputDelta = Y[0] - *target;
        }
        else
        {
            *inputDelta = *target - Y[0];
        }
    }
    
    if(*target > Y[0])
    {
        *out += *inputDelta*T/Tu;
        if(*out > *target)
        {
            *out = *target;
        }
    }
    else if(*target < Y[0])
    {
        *out -= *inputDelta*T/Td;
        if(*out < *target)
        {
            *out = *target;
        }
    }
    
    Y[0] = *out;  
  } 
  else  if (flag == 5) 
  {
    /* ending */
    scicos_free(*(block->work));

  }

}
```

I am able to successfully compile the block containing this code but in case I start the simulation it crashes. I have doubts regarding the dynamic allocation of the memory and the way how I work with it.

Please could anybody take a look at my code (namely the part in the body of the if with flag == 4) and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your use of "probably" does not inspire confidence.  Where is the documentation for the C-language API to which you're trying to program?  That should be your first recourse, before you even start writing code, and there's no way anyone here can advise you without relying on the docs themselves.

Comment: You are dereferencing pointers that are not initialized

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
target      = (double*)(*(block->work));
```

is correct but these lines

```
inputDelta  = (double*)(*(block->work + 1));
out         = (double*)(*(block->work + 2));
```

are wrong.

`(*(block->work)` will give you the pointer to the first of the three malloc'ed doubles.

However, you don't get the next double like you did - you are adding one too early. Change it like:

```
(double*)(*(block->work + 1));   // Wrong !!
(double*)(*(block->work)) + 1;   // Correct !!
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^
Get pointer to malloced     Then add 1 to get to the second malloc'ed double
memory (i.e. the first
malloc'ed double) and use 
it as a double-pointer
```

Or simply do it like:

```
target      = (double*)(*(block->work));
inputDelta  = target + 1;
out         = target + 2;
```

BTW: You don't need all the casting. Just remove it.

**Edit: In a comment OP tells that it still crashes**

The posted code doesn't tell us whether `block->work` has been initialized before calling `Ramp`. If it **hasn't** been initialized before then doing `*(block->work)` will be illegal - and may cause a crash.

So maybe the code is missing something like:

```
/* init */
block->work = malloc(sizeof *block->work);  // Add this line
if((*(block->work) = (double *)scicos_malloc(sizeof(double)*3)) == NULL)
```

Comment: thank you very much for explanation. I have just fixed my mistake (I have decided to use the simpler approach you have suggested) and started the simulation again. Unfortunatelly the result is exactly the same - simulation crashes.

Comment: @L3sek Then you need a debugger (e.g. gdb) to point out where it crash'es. Alternatively, put in a number of print statements to figure it out.

Comment: @L3sek Is `block->work` initialized when you call the function `Ramp` ?

Comment: I have just double checked (with a text file and fprintf usage) that the block->work is initialized to 417531104 value.

Comment: @L3sek Well, printing its value isn't enough. You need to find the code that did it to be sure

Comment: I have just [checked out](https://github.com/kamakshidasan/scilab) the scilab source code (v5.5.2 which I have been working with) and I have inscpected it. Based on that it seems to me that line 787 in the scicos.c module does the initialization of the work pointer.

Comment: The [example in the official docs](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.0/en_US/C_struct.html#Statesandwork_C_struct) doesn't inspire much confidence when it has a global variable `work` initialized *outside a function* as `void**work = block->work;`. Such code wouldn't even compile outside a function!

Comment: From what I can tell, `block->work` is preallocated and not to be allocated by the client code. There are some example usages of allocating `*block->work` in the existing modules that use `scicos_block`, for example: [scilab/modules/scicos_blocks/src/c/assignment.c](http://gitweb.scilab.org/?p=scilab.git;a=blob;f=scilab/modules/scicos_blocks/src/c/assignment.c).

Comment: So, I'd get rid of the existing edit about allocating storage for `block->work` and mention the problem of the `target`, `inputDelta` and `out` variables only being initialized if `flag` is 4.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in user [4386427](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4386427/4386427)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64102786/5264491), `(double*)(*(block->work + 1))` should be `(double*)(*(block->work)) + 1`. This is especially important if `sizeof(double)` and `sizeof(void*)` have different values. (On a typical 64-bit system they would have the same value, but on a typical 32-bit system they would have different values.)

Another serious problem is that when `flag == 1`, the `target`, `inputDelta` and `out` variables contain uninitialized values but are being dereferenced. The variables need to be assigned in the `else if (flag == 1)` block before they can be dereferenced in the same way as in the `if (flag == 4)` block.

I think the code would be cleaner if a `struct` type was defined to hold the working data:

```
struct Ramp_work
{
    double target;
    double inputDelta;
    double out;
};

void Ramp(scicos_block *block, int flag)
{
    struct Ramp_work *work;

    if (flag == 4)
    {
        /* init */
        work = scicos_malloc(sizeof(*work));
        *block->work = work;
        if (work == NULL)
        {
            set_block_error(-16);
            return;
        }
        work->target = 0;
        work->inputDelta = 0;
        work->out = 0;
    }
    else if (flag == 1)
    {
        /* output computation */
        work = *block->work;
        if (U[0] != work->target)
        {
             /* etc. */
        }
        /* etc. */
    }
    else if (flag == 5)
    {
        /* ending */
        scicos_free(*block->work);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have just made the modifications you have suggested. The compilation passed successfully but when I had run the simulation it crashed again.

Comment: @L3Sek I just noticed a bug in my code. In the `else if (flag == 1)` block, `work = block->work;` should be `work = *block->work;`. I'll correct it now.